# Getting Data from EditText, RadioButton and Spinner

Tags: java, android, xml

I search on many websites and many tutorials how can I get the data from editText and radioGroup and  spinner DIRECTLY When the user input the data

I tried with this:

```
MyEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
              if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                  {case1.setName(CaseName.getText().toString());

                  }
                return true;
              }
              return false;
            }
          });
```

but it didn't take the data, I just use button to make that as shown below:

```
Test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 switch (v.getId()) { 
                case R.id.cancel1:
                    try
                    {

                        // 1-Name
                        case1.setName(CaseName.getText().toString());



                    }catch(Exception e){

                    }

                    break;


            }


            }});
```

Can anyone explain what shall I use to save the data in Object(case1) directly when the user input it ?

---

Answer (score 0):

```
 editext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {                    
                         // s is your text .


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                            int after) {


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


                    }
                })
```

for Radio button

```
  checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Perform action on clicks, depending on whether it's now checked
    if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
        Toast.makeText(HelloFormStuff.this, "Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(HelloFormStuff.this, "Not selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
 });
```